# JQGrid - Trying to bind the "new in v4.3.2" events without success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to bind some of the events reported as "new in v4.3.2" in the jqGrid documentation, specifically 'jqGridKeyEnter' or 'jqGridKeySpace' (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events).

What I need to do is to capture the 'space' key on a non editable selected cell in a grid with 'cellEdit:true'. The cell is selected when I move with the cursors keys, but space or enter keydown is not fired. There is no documentation about these new events, am I doing something wrong?

I tried to set in the options like the standard events, like:

```
{
    ...
    jqGridKeySpace: function() { alert('jqGridKeySpace'); }
}
```

Also tried (like the doc samples):

```
$('#mygrid').on('jqGridKeySpace', function (e, rowid, orgClickEvent) {
    alert('jqGridKeySpace');
});
```

But events are not fired. I tried with other new events also, but no luck.

Edit: I'm using 4.6.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your invaluable help. I tried your solution and it works great. But I keep investigating and found a simpler solution (or workaround).

First, this is exactly what I was trying to do:

[image]

Every row acts as a radio button group. By clicking on them, the cell is painted (using "onCellSelect"). But I didn't have a way of doing it by keyboard, because most events are not raised when the cell is not "editable".

So, I changed the cells to "editable" and I set them as a custom edit. As "editable", the cell captures the "enter" key automatically, entering in edit mode. But my "custom_element" function returns a not really editable element like a . So, I can use any of the raised events, i.e. "beforeEditCell" for doing my job, painting the cell and saving the state to the server by ajax. 
And the same event also works if the cell is clicked by mouse (not needing a second event like "onCellSelect").

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is a misunderstanding about usage of `jqGridKeySpace`. It do the same as `onSpace` callback and it works **only in case of usage `bindKeys`** method. Moreover it will not work together with cell editing.

In case of cell editing jqGrid creates small div on the first call of `cellEdit`. See [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.celledit.js#L41), [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.celledit.js#L356) and [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.celledit.js#L410) of cell editing module. So if you will need to capture pressing of th the <kbd>Space</kbd> key you should do something like that

```
var $grid = $('#mygrid'),
    myNavKeyDown = function (e) {
        var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam");
        if (e.which === 32) { // space key
            $("#mylog").remove();
            $("<p id='mylog'>space key pressed on the cell in the row with<br/>" +
                "the row index: " + p.iRow + "<br/>" +
                "the column index: " + p.iCol + "<br/>" +
                "the rowid: " + $grid[0].rows[p.iRow].id + "<br/>" +
                "the column name: " + p.colModel[p.iCol].name + "</p>").appendTo("body");
            return false;
        }
    };
$grid.on("jqGridSelectCell", function () {
    var knv = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "knv");
    if (knv) {
        $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(knv))
            .off('keypress', myNavKeyDown) // remove old handle if exist
            .on('keypress', myNavKeyDown);
    }
});
```

I created [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/spaceKeyOnSelectedCell.htm) for you which demonstrates the code. If you click on any cell of "Client" or "Notes" columns (which are not editable in the demo) then the cell will be selected. Pressing the <kbd>Space</kbd> key will process the event handler and display information about clicked cell below the grid. The results will be like on the picture below

[image]

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your help. I added a comment as a separate answer for better explanation.